# cannot write a file into hdfs - getting error hdfs in safe mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

When I try to copy a file from my `local directory` into the `HDFS` I get the following error:

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal hello.txt /user/cloudera/my_data


copyFromLocal: Cannot create file/user/cloudera/my_data/hello.txt._COPYING_. Name node is in safe mode.
```

Then I executed the command :

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ su
Password: 
[root@localhost cloudera]# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
safemode: Access denied for user root. Superuser privilege is required
```

and further executed the command to store in the file into the `HDFS` I am getting the same error.

Again I executed the command :

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ su - root
Password: 
[root@localhost ~]# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

I am getting the same error.

I am using `cloudera` distribution `hadoop`.

Comment: thanks Maximillian for correcting the format.

Answer (score 3):

From the apache documentation [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode)

> During start up the NameNode loads the file system state from the
>   fsimage and the edits log file. It then waits for DataNodes to report
>   their blocks so that it does not prematurely start replicating the
>   blocks though enough replicas already exist in the cluster. During
>   this time NameNode stays in Safemode. Safemode for the NameNode is
>   essentially a read-only mode for the HDFS cluster, where it does not
>   allow any modifications to file system or blocks. Normally the
>   NameNode leaves Safemode automatically after the DataNodes have
>   reported that most file system blocks are available. If required, HDFS
>   could be placed in Safemode explicitly using bin/hadoop dfsadmin
>   -safemode command.

In most of the case, the process completes within a reasonable time after HDFS is started. However, you can force HDFS to come out of safemode via below command:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

It is strongly recommended to run [fsck](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode) to recover from inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

Namenode will be in safemode for sometimes after restart, If you wait for some time(depends on number of blocks) namenode will leave safe mode automatically.

You can forcefully do the same using the `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave` command, Only HDFS admin user can execute this command, so switch to hdfs user before executing this command.

`su hdfs`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

This should work...